# How can I make this to remember the last modification statement

Tags: javascript

How can I make this to remember the last modification statement. 
Bacause this code is Always reinitialize the str variable.

But I have to make a loop what is add plus one "*" to my str. This is the reason why I want to "save"  the previous statement.

Above I  posted the test results.

```js
function padIt(str, n) {
    do {
        if (n % 2 === 0) {
            str + "*";
        }
        else {
            str = "*" + str;
        }
    } while (n > 5)
    return str;
}
```

I get this:

```
Test Passed: Value == '\'*a\''
Expected: '\'*a*\'', instead got: '\'a\''
Expected: '\'**a*\'', instead got: '\'*a\''
Expected: '\'**a**\'', instead got: '\'a\''
```

Comment: You should mention the way you called `padIt(str,n)` and what was the actual and expected values.

Comment: I get nothing when I click "Run code snippet". Please [edit] the question to include how you're calling this code and getting the specified output.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `+=` in your `if` block. It should be `str += "*";`

```
function padIt(str, n) {
  do {
    if (n % 2 === 0) {
      str += "*";
    } else {
      str = "*" + str;
    }
  } while (n > 5)
  return str;

}
```

Comment: I think this will be output the same as before

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Ferenc _is_ the OP :-)

Comment: @FerencKovacs did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you really intended the `padIt` function to be recursive.  If so, we can attempt such a solution by adding some padding on each side, in each recursive call.  The base case occurs when the `n` counter reaches one, in which case we just return the cumulatively built padded string.

```js
padIt = function(str, n) {
    if (n === 1) return str;
    if (n%2 === 0) {
       return padIt(str + "*", n-1);
    }
    else {
       return padIt("*" + str, n-1);
    }
}

console.log(padIt("a", 5));
```

Comment: @FerencKovacs Your code attempt looked like something halfway between an iterative (loop based) approach, and a recursive approach.  I guess I picked the wrong one :-). ... maybe this answer will help someone else later on.

Comment: Yes It is true :)